# What are the advantages/disadvantages of 3:2 aspect ratio over other aspect ratios?

Tags: laptop, display, microsoft-surface, pixels, aspect-ratio

I have been recently looking at buying a new laptop and came across the Microsoft Surface Laptop 3.

Its display seems to have a 3:2 aspect ratio. Now I have little to no knowledge about aspect ratios and I was wondering what the advantages and disadvantages are of having a 3:2 aspect ratio over something like 16:10, 16:9 and 4:3?

Comment: Read the review below and look under Performance.  The 3:2 aspect ratio may mean stretching some applications to fit.  https://www.techradar.com/reviews/microsoft-surface-laptop-3-15-inch

Comment: I suspect it's the other way around.  Manufacturers don't start with an aspect ratio because it's ideal for a purpose, and then design a device around it.  They design a device and then find the closest aspect ratio display that fits.  Any aspect ratio will be well suited to some tasks and sub-optimal for some others.  It may also entail finding clever ways to rearrange screen components to make best use of the space provided by the aspect ratio.